# How to create and use bundle files with electron?

Tags: bundle, electron

I am working on an electron app, where I want to load and modify a project folder. The project folder should only be modified by the app and easily exchangeable.

A folder is a great source of errors since everyone can enter it and modify the files. I would love to have some kind of protection for it. The best way I can think of is a bundle file. Something like the `.app` bundles from macOS or the `.embersnap` files from Realmac’s Ember app, which behaves as if it were a single file, but contains multiple resources.

Is there a way to use such bundle files with Electron? (Cross platform would be ace)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build in electron archiver asar.

```
var asar = require('asar');

var src = 'some/path/';
var dest = 'name.asar';

asar.createPackage(src, dest, function() {
  console.log('asar archive created.');
})
```

The cool thing about asar is that you can access the files like they are unpacked. For example via the path `./name.asar/some/path/` just make sure to use nodes `fs` for accessing the file.

Comment: The sounds great! I will get back to your answer if I have tested it.